# fast auto-guessing of date strings

Tags: c, string, date, parsing, format

For a huge number of huge csv files (100M lines+) from different sources I need a fast snippet or library to auto-guess the date format and convert it to broken-down time or unix time-stamp.  Once successfully guessed the snippet must be able to check subsequent occurrences of the date field for validity because it is likely that the date format changes throughout the file.

The test set of date formats must be variable but compiling an optimal decision tree or something from a number of given date formats is fine.

I've come to the conclusion that nothing of the kind exists but yet have to do a `market research' hence my question.

My first attempt was to mimic getdate() for 23 different date formats I've observed so far, and to replace the number parsers by optimised versions taking date-specific characteristics into account (no '4' to '9' in the tenners of the day part, no '3' to '9' in the tenners of the month part, etc.)

Did anyone face a similar problem or even produce code of the kind?

Comment: Does each CSV file have just one date format, or are they a mix?

Comment: It's usually just one format per file, but sometimes they change the format throughout the file, probably the result of cat'ting stuff together.
Quite frequently you see an import to a database succeeds for the first 98 million lines, then the next 40 million lines are completely borked.

Comment: It will be somewhat difficult if you have certain date formats.  Is "060804" June 8 2004, Aug 6 2004 (European), or Aug 4 2006 (yymmdd)?  You may not have formats like that, but if you do you're going to have to pick and you may find you picked incorrectly.  If this is an ongoing load, see if you can go back to the source and get them to fix it.  If it's a one-time thing, you're going to have to muddle through.

Comment: Yes thanks for that, forgot to elaborate.  It will be difficult to auto-guess date strings like that from just one line.  But the special nature of the input source (level-1/2 quote data) allows an educated guess if you take a few million lines into consideration as the data is in chronological order and covers at least a year.

Comment: I think the first thing I'd do is see if your list of 23 date formats is complete for a larger sample, one that is as representative as you can get.  The general case problem is unsolveable so you'll have to attune to your actual sources.  I'd worry about files that switch between date formats: might they be broken in other ways, too?

Comment: It's most definitely not complete but works for the set of sources I have to encounter at the moment.  I was planning on writing a little compiler that takes formats in the libc canonical (strptime()'able) %Y%d%m form and turns them into a decision tree.  Much like gperf's -S option.
Then secondly, a tool that takes one of these trees and does a BFS on it to determine valid format specs, then checks if the format specs hold throughout the rest of the file.
I do have code for each of the sources already, I was just thinking of generalising/unifying the interface.

Comment: And yes, the rest of the fields may be broken as well (prices are suddenly multiplied by 10, the decimal separator disappears, etc.). I can't help a broken symbol string, but with a working time stamp and a (supposedly correct) symbol there's a chance to locate oddities because data can simply be imported/sorted/grouped within a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks of excessive googl^Wweb browsing I came to the conclusion that I have to write this one myself.  FTW, my first go at it: http://github.com/hroptatyr/glod

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with timestamped sensor data (structurally CSV) in over fifty formats from numerous sources with a Perl script. Never constrained for functionality, and although it is script based it was reasonably quick (>10Klines/sec where line was ~60-100chars)
I implemented 
a) analyse first couple of hundred lines, rewind and then do the run
           ...to build up context for decision logic.
b) emit erroneous line(s) with line number and context 
           ...so at the end of the run could edit the offending lines then set them to be re-inserted on a subsequent run, so it could pass "patched" error free ie every line would have matched a format.
c) time difference between lines
           ...only allowed increasing timestamps.
d) also I could reformat other stuff like changing units ie imperial to SI.
Although from the C camp, simple Perl is not too alien, but made it so so much easier
Note This method could deal with problems like 10/04/05 ie DD/MM/YY or MM/DD/YY if there was enough information in the file

Comment: Nice one, mind sharing your code? 10k lines/sec was roughly what I had in mind.  I started a simple compiler that takes up to 64 format specs and emits code to do incremental refinement, so in the end I get a bit mask where a set bit denotes that the corresponding format spec did hold throughout the whole file. Could do with your code to validate mine.

Comment: If you get a page of test data to me, I could knock up a demonstrator, just to ease you along the learning curve. You might want to brush up on your regular expressions, as this is used to select your desired data.

Comment: I picked 6 sources, 10000 lines each.
http://qaos.math.tu-berlin.de/~freundt/for_roaker.tar.bz2